# How to do line break using SED in solaris?

Tags: sed, echo

How to use sed for the below scenario where in my prompt i don know the way to delimit \n. 
In the below pattern there should be a new line whenever "no" occurs.

```
yesnoyesno
```

as

```
yes
noyes
no
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/search pattern/
replace pattern on a new line/option'
```

use a real new line (or CTRL+v+j for a one-liner entry)

`\n` on replace pattern is not know as new line in posix sed (but well in search pattern so a `s/foo\(\n\)bar/&\1lazy dog/` will normaly work)

in this request :

```
sed 's/no/
&/g' YourFile
```